# What is the way to enforce daily write limits on a disk partition in linux?

Tags: disk-usage, cgroups, limit

I would like to enforce certain write limits on my disk partitions. I would like to limit the amount of data application can write on a given disk partition on hourly, daily or weekly basis.

Is there a standard way in Linux to specify hourly/daily/weekly write limits on a given disk partition in Linux? `cgroups` V2 seems to be giving option limit IO per second on a given partition but I don't see options for hourly/daily limits.

Comment: these are very coarse units of time. What do you want to happen when something exceeds their limits, exactly?

Comment: I'm not aware of a program that will do something like that based over a time frame.  Disk QUOTA will simply limit user accounts to some absolute value regardless of time.  One way would be to write a BASH or C program, that runs periodically via cron job as root, looking at the `df -h` output and calculating data growth over time of a disk partition then if it exceeds a value to umount that partition or remove write permissions to those folders via `chmod`

Comment: another way which might be attractive, if you have SSD's, is to look at the output from `smartctl` its various parameters regarding SSD writes and wear and lifespan and stuff

Comment: Thanks all for response. I am actually looking this for eMMC to limit the application wearing out eMMC by writing excessive   data. I would like to have deterministic life of eMMC for few years and for that, I would like to set some limits on application. In case of daily limit, If limit exceed, it would throttle writes for that day. Next day again limit would be restored so application can write data with in limit. A side question, is there any other way to have deterministic life of eMMC, so that it last for few years for sure?

Answer (score 2):

These two resources enable you to set time bound write quotas on a disk partition; the first one is the preinstalled xfs_quota utility, and the second is the "quotatool," available through Git Hub.

FIRST RESOURCE: xfs_quota

The xfs_quota is a utility that can be used interactively or through commands. With it, you can set time-specific write quotas based on a given user, a group of users, or a project.

To use administrative commands, start the interactive utility as follows (as part of the command, I include the f switch before a configuration is set to prevent the error "path: foreign filesystem. Invoke xfs_quota with -f to enable."):

```
#xfs_quotas -xf

xfs_quota> help

df [-bir] [-hN] [-f file] -- show free and used counts for blocks and inodes

disable [-gpu] [-v] -- disable quota enforcement

....

Use 'help commandname' for extended help.
```

[Red Hat command example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/xfsquota), to set a soft and hard block limit of 1000m and 1200m, respectively, to group accounting on the /target/path file system, use the following command:

```
xfs_quota -x -c 'limit -g bsoft=1000m bhard=1200m accounting' /target/path
```

Here you can read more about xfs_quota: https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_quota

SECOND RESOURCE: quotatool

Commandline utility for filesystem quotas on Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Solaris and AIX

The time parameter (t) consists of an optional '+' or '-' modifier, a  number, and one of: 'sec', 'min', 'hour', 'day', 'week', and 'month'.

**EXAMPLE THAT ANSWERS YOUR QUESTION**: Set the global block grace period to one week on /home:

```
quotatool -u -b -t "1 week" /home
```

Here you can access this tool: https://github.com/ekenberg/quotatool

Comment: This answer does not seem to answer how the writes per interval can be (if at all) limited by these tools.  Can they?  If you write 1GB then delete 1GB and repeat the whole process, it would seem you can write however many bytes you want to the storage without being stopped by the limits imposed by quota.